# @Async Copy bean scope from one thread to another

Tags: java, spring

I´m using Spring `@Async` to make async request, and I would like to know, how can I pass beans like the Hibernate session from one thread to other when I´m using `@Async`?

Regards.

Comment: Please check my edits to make sure they express more clearly what you want

Comment: Please clarify your question as it isn't entirely clear what you try to solve. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information on how to write a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass the Hibernate session to another thread. Some beans are connected to the current thread. The active database transaction is one such bean. Spring keeps that in a `ThreadLocal` and there is no API to pass this to another thread.

What you will have to do is pass the objects that you want to work on to the new thread, get a new session there and `em.merge()` the objects into the new session. Or, if you want to be really clean, you can just pass the primary keys and load the objects again from Hibernate. Since they will probably be in the cache, this shouldn't be very expensive.

Comment: That´s exactly what I´m doing right now. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just provide the bean scope in ApplicationContext or with Annotation where the bean is declared. You don't have to do anything explicit to copy the scope if the bean is used by multiple threads

Comment: Can you provide an example?. Part of the scope of the bean is for example hibernate session

Comment: I don't understand what do you need an example for?

Comment: To see how do you have on mind it is done. Sorry I dont understand your explanation.